# How to @link to a Enum Value using Javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

Using Javadoc 1.5, I have been unable to create a @link to an Enumeration value.

What I would like to do is to create an Enum like this:

```
public enum Planet { 

/**
* MERCURY is a fun place.
*/
MERCURY, 

/**
* VENUS is more fun.
*/
VENUS, 

/**
* But nothing beats the Earth.
*/
EARTH,

/**
* Others we know nothing about.
*/ 
OTHERS
}
```

And then refer to the Javadoc for Earth using a link like this:

```
{@link Planet.EARTH}
```

I have tried the `{@link Planet#EARTH}` style too, but to no avail.

Anyone know if this is doable at all?

Answer (score 244, accepted):

The `#` style works for me:

```
{@link Planet#EARTH}
```

The key is that the `Planet` package must be imported, or `Planet` must be fully qualified - i.e.:

```
{@link com.yourpackage.Planet#EARTH}
```

Comment: As sfussenegger noted, Eclipse handles the import for you.

Comment: Thanks both answers helpful! I did get it to work using the fully qualified reference. Sometimes the compiler output isn't really helpful in determining what the problem is...

Comment: What if enum is defined within class A and one is trying to reference one of its values from class B javadoc?

I've found neither A.Planet#EARTH nor A#Planet#EARTH to work for OpenJDK 1.6 update 24 javadoc, although eclipse knows to find declaration with A.Planet#EARTH style.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work if you have a static import of enum. At least in intellij idea there is no way to use a statically imported enum in javadoc, unless you use the fully qualified enum name with packages etc.

Comment: This however does not work with static import. Having `import static com.yourpackage.Planet.EARTH` I can not simply use `{@link EARTH}` even though Intellij Idea (2023.2.2) suggests it. It glows red afterwards.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using Eclipse to check this, but

```
{@link Planet#EARTH}
```

style seems to work. However, I normally prefer

```
@see Planet#EARTH
```

anyway. Not sure what Eclipse uses to generate Javadoc, but I'm using JDK6. Still, maybe @see does the trick for you.

Comment: I like `@see` but sometimes you need special cases. For example, my orders have an `isWithdrawn()` method, and I specifically say `@return true if the status of this order is equal to OrderStatus#WITHDRAWN, false otherwise`

Answer (score 2):

As long as it's imported you can link it (but when you do this, IMO it makes the imports messy- what ones are used in code and what ones in javadoc?  I like to just use the fully qualified name).

But yes, Eclipse can take care of it all and standard

```
{@link Planet#EARTH}
```

works fine.

If your using Eclipse, Ctrl + Shift + O (on PC) or Cmd + Shift + O (on Mac) auto-adjust your imports (this means if you have extra imports not being used, they're removed, as well as adding any imports you need).